# Symfony 6.2 and json_login not save authenticated state

Tags: symfony, symfony6

I have config (security.yaml):

```
    firewalls:
        login:
            pattern: ^/api/login
            json_login:
                username_path: email
                password_path: password
                check_path: api_login
        
        main:
            login_throttling:
                max_attempts: 3
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\CustomAuthenticator
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Attribute\CurrentUser;

#[Route('/api', name: 'api_')]

class ApiController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/login', name: 'login', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function login(#[CurrentUser] ?User $user): Response
    {
        if (null === $user) {
            return $this->json([
                'message' => 'missing credentials',
            ], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        return $this->json(['user' => $user->getUserIdentifier()]);
    }
}
```

In debug-panel I see **Authenticated** and i see real getUserIdentifier(). But if I reload the page, then I'm not logged in again. If you move json_login to the main block, then everything works. What is missing?

I tried different custom authorizers, but it didn't help. I also looked at the open repositories in the github but all examples are the same

Comment: API calls are stateless by design. you have to return a auth token to the client which is then used to authenticate each request.  see the last sentences of https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#json-login

Comment: But why does it work then [code](https://pastebin.com/6Zr9VLXC) and after refreshing the page I am authorized on the site, but [code](https://pastebin.com/QxaUTSgi) but it doesn't work here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create separate firewall only for login path - add entries in your `main` firewall.

I cannot find it now, but I can bet that somewhere in Symfony Security docs there is information that login should not have separate firewall. But from docs:

```
Each firewall is like a separate security system, being authenticated in one firewall doesn't make you authenticated in another one.
```

So, you are authenticating in `login` firewall, but then navigating to any endpoint protected by `main` will not work.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Yes, you are indeed right. I misunderstood the documentation. I tried to log in in "login", but I used the site in "main"